# java.lang.stringindexoutofboundsexception in search .mp3 files in emulator android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, indexoutofboundsexception, android-logcat

I'm developing a music player. I'm getting all the files which are ends with .mp3 extensions.
When I run this below code I'm getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundException`,Even if surround the coding with try,catch I'm getting the same error.Please help me.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    try{
    System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){}
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}

private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
    try{
    if (directory != null) {
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

private void addSongToList(File song) {
    try{
    if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
        String title = song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4));
        String path = song.getPath();
        mediaInfo.setDataSource(path);

        String albumName = "unknown",artist = "unknown",genere = "unknown",duration = "unknown",composer = "unknown";

        if(mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM) == null || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM).equals("") || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM).startsWith(" "))
            albumName = "Unknown Album";
        else{
            albumName = mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
        }
        if(mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST) == null || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST).equals("") || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST).startsWith(" "))
            artist = "Unknown Artist";
        else{
            artist = mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
        }
        if(mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE) == null || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE).equals("") || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE).startsWith(" "))
            genere = "Unknown Genre";
        else{
            genere = mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
        }
        if(mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION) == null || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION).equals("") || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION).startsWith(" "))
            duration = "Unknown Duration";
        else{
            duration = mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        }
        if(mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_COMPOSER) == null || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_COMPOSER).equals("") || mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_COMPOSER).startsWith(" "))
            composer = "Unknown Composer";
        else{
            composer = mediaInfo.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_COMPOSER);
        }
        ds.createEntry2(title, path, albumName, artist, genere, duration, composer);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

This is my logcat error :

```
02-26 02:30:54.307: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/
02-26 02:30:54.319: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Android
02-26 02:30:54.323: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Music
02-26 02:30:54.327: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Podcasts
02-26 02:30:54.335: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones
02-26 02:30:54.335: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Alarms
02-26 02:30:54.339: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Notifications
02-26 02:30:54.343: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
02-26 02:30:54.347: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Movies
02-26 02:30:54.351: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/Download
02-26 02:30:54.355: I/System.out(1360): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM
02-26 02:30:54.407: D/AndroidRuntime(1360): Shutting down VM
02-26 02:30:54.407: W/dalvikvm(1360): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b65648)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.vinoch.infaaz.musicseven/com.vinoch.infaaz.musicseven.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at com.vinoch.infaaz.musicseven.MainActivity.getListSongs(MainActivity.java:1890)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at com.vinoch.infaaz.musicseven.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:1083)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-26 02:30:54.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1360):     ... 11 more
```

My getListSong() method :

```
private ArrayList getListSongs() {

    ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    Song Data = new Song();
    Database_Song db = new Database_Song(this);

    String numm = String.valueOf(1);
    String startLetter = ds.getName(numm);
    startLetter = String.valueOf(startLetter.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + "/$#@";

    if(Character.isDigit(startLetter.charAt(0)))
        startLetter = "#" + "/$#@";

    Data = new Song();
    Data.setSongTitle(startLetter);
    Data.setImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.invisible));
    results.add(Data);

    for(int i = 1 ; i < ds.getTotalCount() ; i++){
        String num = String.valueOf(i);
        String currentSongName = ds.getName(num);
        String dummy = "";

        if(Character.isDigit(currentSongName.charAt(0))){
            dummy = "#";
        }
        else
        {
            dummy = String.valueOf(currentSongName.charAt(0));
        }

        if(dummy.toUpperCase().equals(String.valueOf(startLetter.charAt(0)))){
            Data = new Song();
            Data.setSongTitle(currentSongName);
            Data.setAlbumName(ds.getSongAlbumName(currentSongName));
            mediaInfo.setDataSource(ds.print(currentSongName));
            if (mediaInfo.getEmbeddedPicture() != null){
                byte[] img = mediaInfo.getEmbeddedPicture();
                Data.setImage((BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0,img.length)));
            }
            else
                Data.setImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.album_art_low));
            results.add(Data);
        }
        else{
            startLetter = dummy.toUpperCase() + "/$#@";
            Data = new Song();
            Data.setSongTitle(startLetter);
            Data.setImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.invisible));
            results.add(Data);
            i = i-1;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: cam yous end the full log please

Comment: post your stack trace and point to the line the exception was thrown.

Comment: Using stack trace, its print the same error,no different.

Comment: Your log shows that the error was `caused by` the method `getListSongs()` - can you post that code please

Comment: and also indicate `MainActivity.java` line 1890. seems the list is empty. Is there any mp3 files in the specified path?

Comment: No, Even if there is no songs the adapter should show the empty Listview. Am i correct ?

Comment: @Vinoch what is line 1890?

Comment: startLetter = String.valueOf(startLetter.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + "/$#@";

Comment: `startLetter.charAt(0)` index 0 length is 0. meaning startLetter length is 0.

Comment: How to check whether the songs are existed in the emulator or not ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48425/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-vinoch)